# Protractor passes my tests without executing the 'it' blocks

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, pageobjects

I've recently tried to use the Page Object Model with Protractor following this post 
http://engineering.wingify.com/posts/angularapp-e2e-testing-with-protractor/

However, when I run my tests, my `it`blocks do not get executed.

Below is my login page object

```js
/*File Name : loginPage.js*/
var loginPage = function () {
    'use strict';
    this.email = element(by.id('Email'));
    this.next = element(by.id('next'));
    this.pwd = element(by.id('Passwd'));
    this.signin = element(by.id('signIn'));
    this.submitButton = element(by.css('.login-form button[type="submit"]'));
    //this.classitem = element(by.css('hap-class-item'));
    //this.googlesigninbtn = element(by.css('[ng-click="login_google()"]'));

    //******************** functions *******************

    this.enterEmail = function (email) {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        //browser.sleep(2000);
        this.email.clear();
        this.email.sendKeys(email);
        this.next.click();
        browser.sleep(2000);
    };

    this.enterPassword = function (pwd) {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        this.pwd.clear();
        browser.sleep(2000);
        this.pwd.sendKeys(pwd);
        this.signin.click();
        browser.sleep(2000);
    };
};
module.exports = {
    log: new loginPage()
};
```

Below is my logout page object

```js
/*File Name : logoutPage.js*/
var logoutPage = function () {
    'use strict';
  this.logoutcaret = element(by.css('[ng-if="api.userNav.items"]'));
     this.logoutbtn = element(by.css('[ng-click="openModal()"]'));
     this.googlelogout = element(by.css('[ng-click="logout()"]'));
      var EC1 = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    //******************** functions *******************
    this.logoutfn = function () {
     browser.wait(EC1.visibilityOf(this.logoutcaret),15000);
     this.logoutcaret.click();
     this.logoutbtn.click();
     this.googlelogout.click();
    };
};
module.exports = {
    log: new logoutPage()
};
```

Below is my Base Page that has login and logout functions created to be used in each test

```js
/*File Name : LoginOut.js*/
//var switchwin = require('../commons/selectwindow.js');
var loginPage = require('../objects/loginpage.js'),
    eml = 'abc',
    password = 'pwd';

exports.login = function () {
    //browser.driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    browser.driver.get('https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin');
    loginPage.log.enterEmail(eml);
    loginPage.log.enterPassword(password);
    browser.driver.get('URL');
};

var logoutPage = require('../objects/logoutpage.js');
exports.logout = function () {
    logoutPage.log.logoutfn();
};
```

Lastly, below is my test, which always passes but it merely logs in and logs out however does not perform any actions in the 'it' block.

```js
/*File Name : tests*/
'use strict';

describe('I want to test Smartshare', function () {

   var loginMod = require('../commons/loginout.js');
    //login before each test
    beforeEach(function () {
        loginMod.login();
    });
    var loginMod = require('../commons/loginout.js');
    //logout after each test
    afterEach(function () {
        loginMod.logout();
    });

    var smartshareMod = require('../objects/smartsharepage.js');
    //copy doc test
    it('should test sharing a document', function () {
     exports.copydoc = function () {
      smartshareMod.log.copyDoc().then(function(){
       console.log('document copied');
      });
     };
    });
});
```

I have read similar questions but with no help
[Protractor passes tests without running the tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36602467/protractor-passes-tests-without-running-the-tests) and
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2072

```
    node.js version - v6.4.0 
    protractor version - 4.0.11 
    Running on MacOS Sierra 
    webdriver-manager updated to latest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you *don't call any functions* inside the `it()` block, fix it:

```
it('should test sharing a document', function () {
    smartshareMod.log.copyDoc().then(function() {
        console.log('document copied');
    });
});
```

Also note that you don't have to "require" your page objects every time you use them - require them at the top of your test spec once and reuse:

```
'use strict';

var loginMod = require('../commons/loginout.js');
var smartshareMod = require('../objects/smartsharepage.js');

describe('I want to test Smartshare', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        loginMod.login();
    });

    afterEach(function () {
        loginMod.logout();
    });

    it('should test sharing a document', function () {
        smartshareMod.log.copyDoc().then(function() {
            console.log('document copied');
        });
    });
});
```